# Solving the system of equations $a=bc$ and $d = b-c$ for $b$ and $c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Assume for this scenario that:$$\begin{cases}a = b c\\ d = b- c\end{cases}$$

I only know the value for $a$ and $d$ (in this case $0.075$ and $239$, respectively), and I need to solve for both $b$ and $c$. Is this possible to solve given the limited information, and if so, what is the best approach to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as a system of *nonlinear simultaneous equations*. In this case, it is very easy to solve the system.

First, write $b$ in terms of $d$ and $c$, where $d$ is known:

$$b = d+c.$$

Substitute this into the first equation:

$$a = bc = (d+c)c = cd+c^2$$

Solve this for $c$ using the quadratic formula:

$$ c^2+dc-a = 0 \implies c = -\frac{d}{2}\pm \frac{\sqrt{d^2+4a}}{2}$$

Substitute the solutions back into the equation $b = d+c$ to find values of $b$.

Comment: The problem I am running into is, after solving the quadratic equation I get the results `-0.00031` and `-239` and I know neither of those to be possible values. Even as positive values, neither of them make sense given the real world number I am trying to solve for. Any idea as to why this would be?

Comment: I do not know, because I do not have the context of the problem. All I know is that there are finitely many possible solutions given the input data.

Comment: My apologies, you were correct in your approach and I was incorrect in my assumptions. Once I adjusted my assumptions your approach produced correct results. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your two equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
.075 = b\times c \\ 239 = b-c
\end{cases}
$$
Now solve the second equation for $b$ so that $b=239+c$. Plug this into the first equation in place of $b$:
$$
.075 = (239+c)\times c
$$
Do you know how to solve quadratic equations? Once you have the possible values of $c$, plug those back into our equation for $b$ to get the final answer. This method is called eliminating a variable by substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a solution. I recommend checking the exact form (not approximate) as provided by wolfram alpha.

[Solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%20=%20b%20%2a%20c,%20d%20=%20b%20-%20c,%20a%20=%200.075,%20d%20=%20239)

This supports Ed's answer

Comment: Very cool, I did not know wolfram alpha was capable of that kind of analysis. I'll be going back there next time I find myself sans graphic calculator!